# Null values in address, county, state and city keys

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

**LOG:**

```
    2018-03-06T16:45:22.452Z    c24b7465-215d-11e8-aefd-bfbf7ac6d9a8    
    { 
    addressLine1: null,
    addressLine2: null,
    addressLine3: null,
    districtOrCounty: null,
    stateOrRegion: null,
    city: null,
    countryCode: 'US',
    postalCode: '63101' 
    }
```

**Permission was granted through the companion app, 
I got a valid consent Token, apiEndpoint and deviceId**

**Token:** eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhXXX

**Api Endpoint:** https://api.amazonalexa.com
**Device ID:** amzn1.ask.device.AETPMACRXXX

**My Code:**

```
    const token = event.context.System.apiAccessToken
    const apiEndpoint = event.context.System.apiEndpoint
    const deviceId = event.context.System.device.deviceId
    console.log(
      `Token: ${token} \n 
       Api Endpoint: ${apiEndpoint}
       Device ID: ${deviceId}`)
    const deviceAddressService = new Alexa.services.DeviceAddressService()
    const fullAddress = deviceAddressService.getFullAddress(deviceId,apiEndpoint,token).then(data => {
      resolve(data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err.message)
      })
    })
```

[Permission in Developer Portal enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Y98.png)
I only get the postal and country code... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I got only the postal code and country had nothing to do with the code or any settings in the developer portal but with the echo dot itself. In my alexa app under my echo dot the address given only contained the postal code and country